# Keep page alive in scrapy-splash

Tags: javascript, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a page with javascript that I want to scrape with `scrapy-splash` multiple times. Each load of the page takes about 7 seconds, so if possible I'd like to keep the page alive, to continue executing the javascript and retrieving the data. I tried setting cookies to keep the session alive, when I tried to execute the javascript it returned an undefined error, and a 400 error for the request. When running the same `lua` script using the start_url only, it works.

Is there a way to keep the page in a loaded state so I can keep accessing it in the lua script? I'm thinking it might be possible through last_response or `splash:history()`.

```
function main(splash, args)
    splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
    if args.start_url == true then
         assert(splash:go(args.url))
    local entries = splash:history()
    local last_response = entries[#entries].response
    else
        splash:evaljs(args.jscript)
    end
    return {
    url = splash:url(),
    headers = last_response.headers,
    http_status = last_response.status,
    cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
    html = splash:html(),
    }
end
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, but it never worked 100%. I broke it down into stages, by returning the number of elements from the start url. Then used loops within the lua script, by clicking the elements, added the html to an array (or table), and then output that array. It still had errors with memory issues and timeouts, and in the end I scraped the api instead, which I hadn't figured out in the beginning.